# PayPal ExpressCheckout CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile : PROFILESTATUS PendingProfile

Tags: recurring-billing, paypal

I'm having a problem with CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile call - when I send a request using:

```
[TOKEN] => EC-0HX47934KS3525414
[DESC] => Enrolment title
[PROFILESTARTDATE] => 2014-08-05T19:20:42+01:00
[AMT] => 98.16
[BILLINGPERIOD] => Month
[BILLINGFREQUENCY] => 1
[TOTALBILLINGCYCLES] => 2
[INITAMT] => 98.16
```

I get the response:

```
[PROFILEID] => I-VBR32KNHNXWN
[PROFILESTATUS] => PendingProfile
[TIMESTAMP] => 2014-08-05T18:20:45Z
[CORRELATIONID] => 853de87c95475
[ACK] => Success
[VERSION] => 72.0
[BUILD] => 12194268
```

Any idea why am I getting `PendingProfile` instead of `ActiveProfile`?

**EDIT**

The solution was to take the initial payment with `SetExpressCheckout` method - using `L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0` and `L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0` instead of `INITAMT` with `CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile` - once I've done that - everything works just fine.

Comment: Maybe something about the time in the timestamp..??  I've always just used 0's across the board for the time portion of my timestamps when creating these, so basically telling it midnight of the current day.  Give that a shot.

Comment: I think date / time is ok - as it's in the format PayPal asks for, but what I think it might be is the sandbox problem with INITAMT - I've checked a few forums and it seem to be a common problem. I'm going to try and charge the initial amount with the SetExpressCheckout and then only setup the recurring profile with CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile - see if that works.

Comment: Yeah - as expected - it works if I don't use `INITAMT` - instead I used `L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0` and `L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0` with the `SetExpressCheckout` to get the first payment up front.

Comment: You'll need to call DoExpressCheckoutPayment to finalize that first payment if you do it that way.  That would be separate from the CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile request.  If you want to stick with INITAMT you can add FAILEDINITAMTACTION=ContinueOnFailure and that should make it set to Active.

Comment: That's what I've done (DoExpressCheckoutPayment), but setting `FAILEDINITAMTACTION` to `ContinueOnFailure` does not return `ActiveProfile` - it will simply try a few times more - but the response will remain `PendingProfile` on first call of the `CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile`.